# Load a specific page at midnight using Javascript/Jquery/Ajax or HTML5?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

This sounds a bit orthodox, i'll admit.

However i was wondering if there was a way to load a specific website using Javascript/Jquery/Ajax or HTML5?

Reason i ask is because i'm aware there's a method for using cronjobs, but i'm curious to know if there's another method that does not require cron jobs in order for it to function.

> By load a specific page i'm referring to anything really, perhaps a set
>   of words or an iframe.

- Derek

Comment: Or php (your tag), also, what do you mean 'load a specific page'

Comment: All of those you list (Javascript/Jquery/Ajax or HTML5) are clientside technologies, so they'd require a page to already be loaded; then you can replace it at midnight. With PHP (which you tagged with) you can do it serverside: simply pick if it's midnight or not, then `readfile` the appropriate file. You should decide on how long "midnight" is though; the traditional definition is that it's a point in time, closest JavaScript comes to it is milliseconds, and if you require users to hit the millisecond of midnight, not many will see your midnight page.

Comment: When you would tell us what your actual goal is, you might receive a much better answer.

Comment: I know you say not cronjobs but can you say why not. If there is an issue with that we should give a better solution (cost, reliability etc)

Comment: I just saw another interpretation of the question, where you just want to access a certain page, not show it to users, at midnight. In that case, `curl` in `crontab` is the right way to do it.

Comment: @ManofSnow, Amadan, and tim.baker -- I've edited my question to address your concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have a page already loaded, so let's say this is the javascript in  `index.html`:

```
var now = new Date(),
    then = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate(),
        0,0,0),
    diff = now.getTime() - then.getTime();
```

that will see the milliseconds since midnight.  Now the code below will redirect to a page (or text) if it's within 1 minute of midnight:

```
document.onload = function()
{
    var now = new Date(),
        then = new Date(
            now.getFullYear(),
            now.getMonth(),
            now.getDate(),
            0,0,0),
        diff = now.getTime() - then.getTime();
    if(diff <= 60000)
    {
        //Un-comment first line to go to page, second to change text of page
        //window.location.href = 'pageToLoad.html';
        //document.body.innerHTML = 'yourText';
    }
}
```

Comment: So i take it, if i'd like to display a text then all i would need to do is implement your code, correct?

Comment: Yes, at exactly 12:00 to 12:01 pm you would see 'yourText' displayed on the page, if you un-comment it out.  To display text, just put `document.onload = function() { document.body.innerHTML = 'yourText' }`

Comment: So what happens before that? is it possible to display a 'blank' page?

Comment: Yes, by 'deleting' all HTML (`document.body.innerHTML ='<body></body>';`)

Comment: @DerekHarper Did this work for you?  If so, it would please me if you accept this answer, or another answer just so I know the problem was resolved.

Comment: Worked like a charm for my sister's tumblr page. So sorry for the very late response.

Comment: It's fine, I'm still very much around. Also, now that im better at html, u can just `document.innerHTML='';`

Answer (score 0):

Like you already know there are cron jobs (server side) wich allow you to execute some php scripts at a precise time on your server/host.

If you want that your users see different pages at a certain hour of the day(or a specific time) by loading different content with ajax . Here is a very short example.

1.ajax function for modern browsers(chrome,safari,ie10,ios,android..)

2.time check

3.get night or day content.

```
function ajax(a,b,c){//url,function,just a placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open('GET',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.send()
}

var h=new Date().getHours();
// if it's after 12pm & before 6am it returns night else day.
nightday=(h>0&&h<6?'night':'day')+'.php';

//get the data from file 'day.php' or 'night.php'
ajax(nightday,function(){
 //this.response is the content
 console.log(this.response);
});
```

if you want to execute this just once:

```
 window.onload=function(){
  var c=new XMLHttpRequest,h=new Date().getHours();
  c.open('GET',(h>0&&h<6?'night':'day')+'.php');
  c.onload=function(){console.log(this.response)};
  c.send()
 }
```

And from here there are now various ways to check what time it is.

on every click,on some specific clicks,setTimeout(bad),setIntervall(bad)..and much more.

night.php

```
<?php
//load the content for night
?>
```

day.php

```
<?php
//load the content for day
?>
```

Comment: VERY Late Response, SO SORRY! -- I haven't executed this code, but i'll try it out when i have a chance and get back to you. (Chances are, it works!)